# Docker Cloud and JHipster console

Tags: jhipster

Is it possible to set up JHipster console on Docker Cloud? My application is deployed on Heroku.
If is there no option, please advise where can I set up docker in cloud.
Regards!

Answer (score 1):

Yes docker cloud is an option although I've never tried it. If you have simple needs and don't need container orchestration on multiple hosts I would recommend creating a simple VM with docker on your favorite cloud provider (using docker-machine for example) and then deploy the console there using docker-compose. It's really easy to do.

Comment: I have no experience with docker, I need docker for ELK stack. I didn't find any tutorial how to make this. Could You describe steps (with details)?

Answer (score 0):

1) SSH on your server
2) Install docker and docker-compose
3) Get the docker-compose file from https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-console/blob/master/bootstrap/docker-compose.yml
4) Run `docker-compose up -d`

The console will be available on port 5601.
Refer to the docs at : https://jhipster.github.io/monitoring/

More advanced setup are possible but this is the easiest way to go. Also note that it is perfectly possible to run the JHipster-Console without Docker but it requires some work. To do this, setup an ELK stack yourself usinh on simple logstash configuration and scripts to preload the dashboards.

Comment: Please, tell me more about 1) it's ssh from Heroku? What next with ssh and local docker?

Comment: What's more... I'm using Windows 7, and can't install docker locally... Any idea?

Comment: I meant SSH to any Linux server. You can install docker on Windows either with docker4windows or the docker toolbox and we have instructions in the JHipster docs to help you set it up. If docker is a bother to you, you might also consider using some other monitoring tools.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, locally everything is fine. So how (step by step) push JHipster Console to docker-cloud and connect it with my application on heroku?